# Secret manager cross library

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core

I am using .Net Core console app with the secret manager. The thing is that I need some of the data contained in the ConfigurationRoot (connectionString for example) to be passed to a library. What I did is create a class on the library with an Static field and populate it on my console app:

Library:

```
public class MyLibrary
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Config;
}
```

Console App:

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddUserSecrets()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        MyLibrary.Config = Configuration;
```

Is this approach correct or there is a simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the appropriate approach to loading the appSettings.json upon application start.

Maybe you could do constructor injection like so:

```
public class MyLibrary
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public MyLibrary(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

In your Main()...

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddUserSecrets()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
var config = builder.Build();

MyLibrary lib = new MyLibrary(config);
```